# Is it possible to add a .java file to my eclipse folder and have it appear in the output directory without being compiled?

Tags: java, eclipse

Let's say I have a folder that contains various typs of files. Some of them are regular .java files that are to be compiled, others are in their own format and others are .java files that are not to be compiled (but I want them to appear in the */bin/* folder). Is it possible to  accomplish that in Eclipse?

I've tried taking it out of the build path but them it won't appear in the output folder :(

The following screenshot depicts an example situation: I want `Tests.java`, `X.java` and `Value.java` to be compiled to the output folder `bin/creates_java_contracts_file`. In that same folder, I'll want to have `rfn.rfn`, `Value.spc` and `X.spc`, plus `ValueContractsClass.java`(uncompiled).

[image]

Comment: You really need to let us know what build system you're using. (ANT/Maven/...)

Comment: I am using the standard Eclipse package. No ants or mavens here.

Comment: Then I believe you can't. Eclipse can compile things, but it doesn't have a proper build system. You can set up ANT quite easily though. http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Apache_Ant/Getting_Started - in ANT you'd copy using <copy file="..." todir="..."/>

Comment: I think it'd be easier to watch a .bat script to do a file copy instead of getting involved with ANT.

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative is to either copy the files over to `bin` yourself, or change the file extension from `.java` to whatever you want (say, `.njava` or `.foo`).

I'm guessing you want to retain the `.java` files for some specific reason?

**UPDATE**

1. Exclude them from the build path, as you tried
2. Manually copy the .java files to your output folder

This prevents the files from being compiled, and they will survive a "Clean..." build, by my testing, meaning they don't get deleted when Eclipse scrubs the output folder.

Comment: Yes. I'd like to mantain them as .java files as they are to be later on compiled by another tool. In the worse case I can change its extension, but I was only wondering if I could maintain the extension intact.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ANT, you can do a simple file copy.

Comment: I'm not using ant or any kind of thing like that, just standard Eclipse.